# How to test custom events with Jasmine (using Backbone)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I have a function below that is bound to a button click. Code below part of TeaserView class.

```
addCard: function() {
   if(!this.model.get("loggedIn")){
      Backbone.pubSub.trigger("Signup");
      return;
    }

     this.showAddCardDialog();
  }
```

This is my test method

```
it("Should trigger signup event when clicked and not logged in", function(){
   Backbone.pubSub = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
   signupCallback = jasmine.createSpy("Signup");
   //Backbone.pubSub.on("Signup", signupCallback);
   teaserView = new TeaserView({
     el: "#teaser",
            model: this.model //was created in setup call
     });

     $("#addCard").trigger("click");
     expect(signupCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

But my test to check if the Backbone.pubSub custom event was called fails.  How do I test the listening for this event correctly?

Comment: Why is this commented out? `Backbone.pubSub.on("Signup", signupCallback);`?

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for this and found the answer in your question. Like Chris said, why is it commented? it works fine if it is not commented as there is no other way signupCallback will be called

Answer (score 1):

Your given test code isn't actually listening to the signup event.

```
signupCallback = jasmine.createSpy("Signup");
```

Isn't what you want.

```
signupCallback = jasmine.createSpy();    
Backbone.pubSub.on('Signup', signupCallback);
```

Should get you what you want.

In this new code, the signupCallback is being assigned as an event callback, so triggering the event should call the spy callback.